# How to create a Model object in Yii PHPUnit test without a fixture?

Tags: php, object, yii, phpunit, fixtures

I am writing a PHPUnit test for my Yii application. I read [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.fixture):

> Tip: Having too many fixture files could increase the test time
>   dramatically. For this reason, you should only provide fixture files
>   for those tables whose content may change during the test. Tables that
>   serve as look-ups do not change and thus do not need fixture files.

I indeed have a large fixture (180 records, which takes >20 seconds to load), which is only used as a look-up. However, I do need to transform it easily from an associative array into a Model object, like you can usually do with the fixture syntax below. The tip suggests that there is also a way to create a Model object without the use of a fixture, but does not mention *how* this is done. Can anyone help out?

*Creation of Model object with a fixture:*

```
// tests/fixtures/Order.php
return array(
    'row_id' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'hello',
    )
)

// tests/unit/AbcTest.php
public $fixtures = array(
    'orders' => 'Order',
)

public test_abc()
{
    $order = $this->orders('row_id');
    ....
}
```

Comment: You need just build array with **CActiveRecord**s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option:

when you create **db migration** you should apply it on **production** db and on **test** db moreover you should populate test tables with test data.

Benefits of this approach:

1. You will run populate sql just once (not like
   fixture - each time invokes test).
2. Your test will executes fast, because db will be prepared.
3. When you commit new feature that need new test with new data in db -
   you create db migration, and it will be executed just once, in
   explicit way.

For example:

```
<?php

class m150608_110143_init extends CDbMigration
{
    public function safeUp()
    {
        $sql1 = "
            CREATE TABLE brand (
                id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
                name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                PRIMARY KEY (id)
            );
        ";
        $sql2 = "
            INSERT INTO brand VALUES
                (null, 'aston martin', 'UK'),
                (null, 'audi', 'Germany'),
                (null, 'bmw', 'Germany'),
                (null, 'citroen', 'France'),
                (null, 'peugeot', 'France'),
                (null, 'porsche', 'Germany'),
                (null, 'toyota', 'Japan'),
                (null, 'ferrari', 'Italy')
            ;
        ";
        // Production db.
        $this->setDbConnection(Yii::app()->db);
        $this->execute($sql1);
        // Test db.
        $this->setDbConnection(Yii::app()->dbUnitTest);
        $this->execute($sql1);
        // Populate test db with fixtures.
        $this->execute($sql2);
        return true;
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $sql = 'DROP TABLE brand;';
        // Test db.
        $this->setDbConnection(Yii::app()->dbUnitTest);
        $this->execute($sql);
        // Production db.
        $this->setDbConnection(Yii::app()->db);
        $this->execute($sql);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in test you don't have to think about fixtures.

Comment: This is indeed somewhat like I worked around it. I didn't use a Yii DB Migration, but I did fill my test database manually using simple SQL statements. I was hoping an intermediate form though: automatically filling the test database once for all test cases in a test class, to guarantee that the database is properly filled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to reach what you wish.

For example: i have model **brand** that have own fixture:

```
<?php
// protected/tests/fixtures/brand.php

return [
    1 => [
        'name' => 'Lexus',
        'country' => 'JPN',
    ],
    2 => [
        'name' => 'Acura',
        'country' => 'JPNE',
    ],
];
```

and i have next code:

```
    $brand = new Brand;
    $allBrands = $brand->findAll();
```

This code will return array with 2 **CActiveRecord** objects. And everything what we need - it's just build the same array with 2 CActiveRecord objects:

```
public function testGetAllAvailableBrands()
{
    // Get brands from fixture.
    $brand = new Brand;
    $allBrandsFromFixture = $brand->findAll();
    // Generate brands.
    $lexus = new Brand;
    $lexus->scenario = 'update';
    $lexus->name = 'Lexus';
    $lexus->country = 'JPN';
    $lexus->id = 1;
    $lexus->setPrimaryKey(1);
    $lexus->setIsNewRecord(false);
    $allBrandsGeneratedAtRuntime[] = $lexus;
    $acura = new Brand;
    $acura->scenario = 'update';
    $acura->name = 'Acura';
    $acura->country = 'JPNE';
    $acura->id = 2;
    $acura->setPrimaryKey(2);
    $acura->setIsNewRecord(false);
    $allBrandsGeneratedAtRuntime[] = $acura;
    // Brands from fixture should be equals to generated brands.
    $this->assertEquals($allBrandsFromFixture, $allBrandsGeneratedAtRuntime);
}
```

This test will be green because our brands exactly the same. You cat try something like this.

But i think that native yii fixtures looks much better, and to avoid increase the test time you should use **.init.php** files...

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. Building an array of CActiveRecords manually seems very cumbersome, since I have 100+ records. You mention to use init.php files, but my question was: *how* to use init.php files?

Comment: Okay. I spend some time to understand how this .init.php works - and it little bit unclear, because:
there are no requirements for this file, it should be a valid PHP script.
The framework just looking for .init.php file, and if this file exists - framework will just requires it.
That's all what official documentation tells for us...
Even you place your logic in this script it will executes each test run - and it tedious anyway...
That's why i think for you next answer should be better http://stackoverflow.com/a/31210361/3612353